# Example of Repopulating DataTables Grid After Searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am new to using the DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery and have been able to retrieve data from a back end database and display it within a grid successfully. This is being done during $(document.ready()). I have created a page which presents some search criteria which would repopulate the table when the user submits the page. Can someone provide a simple example showing how to repopulate the new results with the table as a result of a submit? I'm using MVC as well which I'm also tackling for the first time which may be part of the problem.

Below is the jQuery code I've tried but it does not bind the results to the already existing table. I've also specified the ajax source only as well in the options thinking that the table already has the other options set and the ajax source is all that needs to be changed.

Thanks,
Tom

```
$('#SubmitForm').on('submit', function (e) { 
    table = $('#grid').DataTable();
    table.sAjaxSource = "GetEmails";
    table.bServerSide = true;
    table.bProcessing = true;
    table.aoColumns = [
        { "sName": "Id" },
        { "sName": "Email" },
        { "sName": "Reason" },
        { "sName": "Name" },
        { "sName": "Organization" },
        { "sName": "Email_Verified_Date" }
    ];

    return true;
});
```

The browser only displays the output of the ajax source as shown below.

> {"sEcho":null,"iTotalRecords":94,"iTotalDisplayRecords":94,"aaData":[]}

Below are excerpts of my views which show how I'm using the DataTable.

This works - notice the DataTable is rendered and populated during the page load via document.ready.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>How to use jQuery Grid with ASP.NET MVC</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var oTable = $('#grid').dataTable({
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "home/GetEmails1",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "aoColumns": [
                                { "sName": "Id" },
                                {"sName": "Email"},
                                {"sName": "Reason"},
                                { "sName": "Name" },
                                { "sName": "Organization" },
                                { "sName": "Email_Verified_Date" }
                ]
            });
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="grid">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Reason</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Organization</th>
                    <th>Email Verified Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the second view that does not work. Here I am attempting to take search criteria, submit and populate the table with the search results. Both the ajax calls from the working example above and the non-working example here return the same results from the ajax call. I included the page load example in this view as well thinking that this may help that the DataTable is already initialized for when the search is completed and its to be repopulated. Thanks for your help!

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.ACORD360VerifiedEmail

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Search Page</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var oTable = $('#grid').dataTable({
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    //"sAjaxSource": "GetEmails",
                    "sAjaxSource": "GetEmails",
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "aoColumns": [
                                    { "sName": "Id" },
                                    { "sName": "Email" },
                                    { "sName": "Reason" },
                                    { "sName": "Name" },
                                    { "sName": "Organization" },
                                    { "sName": "Email_Verified_Date" }
                    ]
                });

        $('#SubmitForm').on('submit', function (e) { //use on if jQuery 1.7+
            table = $('#grid').DataTable();
            table.ajax.reload();

            return true;
        });
    })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("GetEmails", "ACORD360VerifiedEmail", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SubmitForm" }))
    {
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h2>Lyris - ACORD360 Integration</h2>
            <p class="lead">This allows you to modify Lyris and ACORD360 email data.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailVerifiedStartDate)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailVerifiedStartDate,
          new { @class = "form-control date-picker", placeholder = "Enter date here", id = "EmailVerifiedStartDate" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailVerifiedEndDate)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailVerifiedEndDate, new { @class = "form-control date-picker", placeholder = "Enter date here", id = "EmailVerifiedEndDate" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrganizationName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrganizationName)
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br /><br /><br />
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="grid">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Reason</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Organization</th>
                        <th>Email Verified Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <br /><br />
                <label id="Error"></label>
                <label id="Info"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, it doesn't look like your changing any of the data:

```
$('#SubmitForm').on('submit', function (e) { //use on if jQuery 1.7+
        table = $('#grid').DataTable();
        table.ajax.reload();

        return true;
});
```

On submit, you're reloading the table and then posting the form.  If you're going to ajax source your data, use jquery to post the data and then on success reload the table:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url, type: 'POST',
   success: function() {

       table.ajax.reload();
   }
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("Sorry. Server unavailable.");
     });
```

Comment: I tried this but get the same result. I have verified that the results are the same when returning from the ajax call for both the working and non-working scenarios.

Here is the snippet of code I used:

table = $('#grid').DataTable();
table.ajax.reload();

Comment: What do you mean by working and non-working scenarios?  How are you submitting the data?  How are you expecting it to be changed?

Comment: I added code for both the working and non-working views above in the main post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found a great article about using F12 in Chrome which I've used in the past but not in this way which shows there is a discrepancy with the response between the two views. I am going to dig into this tomorrow and will update the thread with my findings.

Comment: Thank you for following up on this. I have a learned a lot about working primarily on the client side in the last few weeks. I am going to implement your suggestion about reloading the data. I do have one additional question. Is there a best practice when it comes to submitting the form as opposed to just processing a click event and reloading the data?

Comment: I typically just use an onclick event on a button and post the form with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had a lot to learn between MVC, ajax and DataTables. I ended up using the button click for buttons rather than using submit. It has worked out well. I have to say it's refreshing using this approach after spending so much time with ASP.Net Web Forms. Thanks for all who chimed in with suggestions.